# Wakanda JSON.stringify issue

Tags: javascript, json, wakanda

i´m working with wakanda 1.1.1.0 on windows 2012 R2 Standar.
On server-side, JSON.stringify(someObjectArray), omit the last object in the array.

Comment: Do you have any example, you can share with us ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is not reproducible for me, i have tried with  :

```
var person = [{ firstName : "John", lastName :  "Doe",  num : 46}, { name2 : "issac", num : 25}];
JSON.stringify(person);
```

I get the expexted result

`"[{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","num":46},{"name2":"issac","num":25}]"`

Can you share the array you are using ?

Comment: Thanks issam. I can´t reproduce it again either. May be some mistake by myself.